# Bad font rendering in Mac Chrome for light color on dark background (white on grey)

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

I am building a website with use of Folio Condensed Light typeface. I bought the font from MyFonts and downloaded the font-face kit.
Got a bad rendering issue on
Mac Maverix / Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114

What is strange is that the font is working quite correctly with a dark color on light background :
[image]

But when light color on dark background it is very bad.
I tried every css tricks but nothing work (webkit-font-smooting, text-stroke, ...).
I feel stuck!
Any idea will be appreciated!

RENDERING :
Chrome VS Firefox VS Safari
[image]

Here is the link to see my website :
http://www.lelevateurdecompetences.com/certifications-qualifications

Added

```
text-rendering: optimizelegibility;
```

but not really better.
[image]

Comment: `text-rendering: optimizelegibility;` Should make it a bit easier to read

Comment: I added it thank you, but as you can see it changes the space between letters, but not improved the font-smoothing.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set a font-weight or font-stye on FolioCon-Lig, which may be affecting the rendering, but before you do, I recommend you read this: http://www.fontspring.com/support/installing_webfonts/style-linking

It's a best practice way for dealing with @font-face font weights and styles.

Comment: Yes I had font-weight or font-stye set in my previous original font-face but this one was MyFont webkit. I added it now but it does not help anything sorry. Also I know about style linking but it is just a matter of code improving and not good for IE8 and compatibility.